# Unwanted boxes around fields in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-gridview, flutter-debug

My flutter app is a cross platform app that runs fine on Ios but when I run it on android i get the following boxes around fields and text in my flutter app

some says debug must be on but i haven't opened debug or layout inspection anything. I have tried everything upto my best but it isn't getting resolved. if any of you have faced same issue kindly help.

[image]

Comment: try deleting the existing emulator and create a new one

Comment: and once try running it on a real time device as normal apk , if its working properly we can get to know the issue with that

Comment: Thanks @KarishmaNadar. The issue was resolved by setting  checkerboardRasterCacheImages to false in main.